# Why is Craft CMS attempting to connect with SSL3

Tags: error-message

When either of two of our admin logins attempt to add a new admin user and select to send an activation email, we get this error message:

> Internal Server Error  stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed

Why is Craft CMS attempting to connect with SSL3 which is intentionally disabled at the server level due to known vulnerabilities?

Answer (score 2):

The error is coming from when Craft tries to send out an activation email for the new user.

In Craft's email settings (Settings->Email), you're telling Craft to connect to your email provider over SSL (TLS), but it looks like your local OpenSSL certificate config is setup improperly on your box.

More info here: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#php-56-certificate-verification-failure

I definitely wouldn't recommend their workaround of disabling SSL certificate verification as that opens up a slew of security issues, but would fix the local OpenSSL configuration.